# Separating islands into individual rasters from island chain mosaic using QGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3

I've manually created mosaics of some island chains using the SRTMGL1 v3 data, for example the Hawaiian Islands. From a mosaic, I want to create a set of separate rasters for each of the islands. (I'd be happy to also exclude 'small' islands.)

[image: raster mosaic of hawaiian islands SRTM]

I want to be able to automate it as much as possible, as I'll eventually want to do it for a series of island groups. Using PyQGIS seems like the best option, but I am a little stuck with how to begin.

I've tried by polygonising the raster to create masks, but I need to manually select polygons from the result, and manually remove boundary polygons.

[image: hawaiian islands polygonised]

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: @PolyGeo I didn't involve any code yet as I wanted some help with the design of the workflow. There is no code - as I stated I am not sure where to begin. Can you please reopen the question? Or do you want me to reword it?

Comment: As soon as a question strays too far from "this is a particular thing that what I want to do, this is precisely what I've tried and this is where I'm stuck" it starts to be hard to recognize as focused Q&A.  For coding questions (and your PyQGIS mention in the body and PyQGIS being amongst the tags indicate that you are asking a coding question) we ask that you include a coding attempt rather than just asking for coding help.  If you are not yet at a coding stage then perhaps you can start testing a QGIS Modeler workflow and ask about where you are stuck with that.